# How to filter the array by multiple element and find the sum in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm trying to filter my array by some element. I want recordtype is contain "Income" and createdAt equal to a date but `$0.createdAt!` is an date type so I can't use `.contain("")`, what can I use?

```
recordFilter = record.filter { $0.recordtype!.contains("Income") /*|| $0.createdAt! = recordItem.createdAt!*/}
```

recordFilter output: (this result is not filter by createdAt yet)

```
[<Record: 0x600000099fa0> (entity: Record; id: 0xd0000000003c0000 <x-coredata://913F25A5-B2C9-4646-9091-5EFE7F906908/Record/p15> ; data: {
    accountbook = "first book";
    amount = "\U00a59.99";
    assest = nil;
    category = "\U6295\U8d44";
    createdAt = "2017-11-16 16:00:00 +0000";
    date = nil;
    id = 15;
    recordtype = "\U6536\U5165";
    remark = "";
    toAccBook = nil;
}), <Record: 0x600000099ff0> (entity: Record; id: 0xd000000000400000 <x-coredata://913F25A5-B2C9-4646-9091-5EFE7F906908/Record/p16> ; data: {
    accountbook = "first book";
    amount = "\U00a56.58";
    assest = nil;
    category = "\U5de5\U8d44";
    createdAt = "2017-11-16 16:00:00 +0000";
    date = nil;
    id = 16;
    recordtype = "\U6536\U5165";
    remark = "";
    toAccBook = nil;
})]
```

After that, I trying to get all the amount string in array and sum it. But I found that it's all separate string when I use this code, how can I group it in array and sum it or have any other way to do it?

```
let sum = recordFilter.map({Int($0.amount!.dropFirst())})
//[nil, nil]

for i in 0..<recordFilter.count{
    if recordFilter[i].amount != nil{

        let amountList = recordFilter[i].amount!.dropFirst()
        print(amountList) // I found that it's separate string.
        //9.99
        //11.22
        // ...

        //let intArray = amountList.map { Int($0)!}
        //let sum = amountList.reduce(0, +)
        //print(sum)

    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear that much. give some extra code and proper description so other user can understand easily. @Wan jern

Comment: ok, I edited the question @VishalPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If you want to fulfil two cases (`recordtype` == `Income` && `createdAt` == `Your Date`) so why you are not filtering using the `&&`?

```
recordFilter = record.filter { return $0.recordtype!.contains("Income") && $0.createdAt! == recordItem.createdAt!}
```

Please give a try and let me know if I am missing something?

If you want to sum here you go:

```
recordFilter.map{($0["amount"] as! Float)}.reduce(0, +)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! How can I get all the amount after that? because i want to sum it. `let sum = recordFilter.map({Int($0.amount!.dropFirst())}).reduce(0,+)` something like this but I got error @Sohil R. Memon

Comment: I can't covert the string array to int array

Comment: @WanJern Amount is `String`, `Double` or `Float` ?

Comment: Opps, I changed it to Float already. how to sum it ? I got this error when I use `reduce(0, +)`. `Cannot invoke 'reduce' with an argument list of type '(Int, _)'` @Sohil R.Memon

Comment: Hi, I found that double is limited in hundred number. how to expand it, is it possible? @Sohil R.Memon

Comment: What will be largest number from your side?

Comment: around 14 character --> 100,000,000.00 @Sohil R. Memon

Comment: @WanJern You can go with `NSNumber`.